# Filter Json data into require structure

Tags: javascript, json

I´m trying to lear how to filter json data and I have a task where I'm totally stuck.

I call endpoint which return me following json which i need restructure.

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2014-12-04",
  "title": "TITLE"
  "content": "content"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "date": "2015-12-04",
  "title": "TITLE"
  "content": "content"
 },
 ...
]
```

I need to filter this json into scructure where items are grouped by year. such as following ->

```
[
 {
  "year": 2015
  "contents" [ {..}, {..} ]
 },
 {
  "year": 2014
  "contents" [ {..}, {..} ]
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: Can you please include what you've tried on your own so far?

Comment: This is not `filter` operation , this is called as `group_by`. also what all the properties each element of contents array holds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each items in the JSON array sent by the API to construct the desired output.

First use the built in `Date()` functions to get year from each items. Then construct an object where `key` is unique `year` in given set of data, then group element when year is matched. Once grouped, it can be transformed to any structure.

**Sample Code:**

```
/* STEP 1: Create a temp object to store year wise data - Grouping */
 const obj = {};
 data.map(item => { 
   const year = new Date(item.date).getFullYear();
   obj[year] ? obj[year].push(item) : obj[year] = [item];
 });

/* STEP 2: Transform data to desired format - Transforming */
 const result = Object.keys(obj).map(year => ({year: year, contents: obj[year]}));
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/79n3btr0/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newData = [];

data.forEach(entry => {
  const year = entry.date.split('-')[0];
  if (!newData[year]) newData[year] = [];
  newData[year].push(entry);
});

/* newData is in this format:
{
  '2014': [{..}, {..}],
  '2015': [{..}, {..}]
}
*/

// To get your desired format we do this
const finalData = Object.keys(newData).map(year => ({ year: year, entries: newData[year] }));
```